# How would one login to Azure cloud classic service instance?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-services

I have setup a azure cloud classic. Where I have two instances running one is web role and orleans silos. I want to enable trace and I need a means to login into the box and see the logs. Azure portal is not providing the logs I needed. I am following the following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop but, in the first step, is to click on the cloud service and click configure but I do not see configure option anywhere. I see only 'Pin, swap and delete'. But I did see an option when click on the cloud class, called configuration. In that configuration, there is nothing for remote desk top.

I do have an option for remote desk top, but when I click that I get an message **"This deployment is using RemoteAccess and/or RemoteForwarder modules. We recommend using the RDP extension instead. You can enable this mode by removing the modules from your .csdef and .cscfg and then saving your RDP configuration here."**

so my basic question, how what is proper way to remote to that box provided I am getting above mentioned message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you are using [Azure new portal](https://portal.azure.com) to configure Remote Desktop. For a simple way, you could log into [Azure classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) to leverage Remote Desktop Extension approach for you to enable Remote Desktop even after your application is deployed.

[image]

[image]

**Note:** For more details, you could follow the section about configuring Remote Desktop from the Azure classic portal in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop).

> so my basic question, how what is proper way to remote to that box provided I am getting above mentioned message?

You could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop) about configuring Remote Desktop in the service definition file.