# Remote Desktop Azure Cloud Service Classic

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am a small business owner with a background in IT. I have some development experience including Visual Studio, but consider myself a novice at best. I hired a developer to migrate my standalone website to an Azure cloud services solution. The application is up and operational, but he has split the scene. I have full ownership of the subscription being used but that does not seem to be good enough. I am trying to figure out how to connect to he web hosting server and modify some SQL.

When I click on the Remote Desktop option for the cloud service I get this message

> This deployment is using RemoteAccess and/or RemoteForwarder modules. We recommend using the RDP extension instead. You can enable this mode by removing the modules from your .csdef and .cscfg and then saving your RDP configuration here.

If I drill into the cloud service to the actual site there is a connect button presented. However, when I hit that button I get an error.

> Failed to download the file Error details: error 400 Bad Request

I'm at a loss as to how to get access and control back over my code.

Comment: maybe the best choice is to get the Azure developer support: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/ it is about $30 per month.

Comment: Indeed. Cha-Ching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assumed that you could leverage [Azure classic portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/) to configure Remote Desktop Extension to enable Remote Desktop even after your application is deployed. Also, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-enable-remote-desktop) about configuring Remote Desktop in your service definition file to enable remote desktop. Additionally, there is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687846/how-would-one-login-to-azure-cloud-classic-service-instance/41688461), you could refer to it.

Comment: Thank you, I've looked at the classic portal and the tutorial, but don't find any of the options available to me. I've opted for Developer support as suggested above, but I'll continue to click around and study the similar issues.